# How to Scroll to specific element in xamarin ui test for iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I want to scroll the page until an required element(required element is invisible-Which is  visible only after scrolling the page) matches

I tried with both ScrollDownTo() and ScrollDown() 
1. app.ScrollDown("text")
2. app.ScrollDownTo(c=>c.Class("UITableViewSectionElement").Index(1))

But it is not working, can any one please suggest me what is the right way to scroll specific element

Answer (score 0):

First of all try using the All() method in your query. The All() method lets you operate even on invisible elements.

Try something like:

```
app.ScrollDownTo(c=>c.All().Class("UITableViewSectionElement").Index(1))
```

And here you have more info about the All method:
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery.All/